# Google maps app does not exist google maps xml

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-maps

How can I fix this problem? I explatined the given below pictures.

[image: Google Maps Xml Doesn't appear]

When I run this classpath got error like this picture

[image: When I run this classpath got error like this picture]

Comment: hey there! are you trying to add a third party library? Or google maps dependencies? can you give a bit more detail of what you are trying to do? :D thanks

Comment: Nope i was trying to google maps activity but  google maps xml file didnt appear this project.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as your error says you need to put your build block before any plugins. So, here is a way to do around it:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       google()
}
    dependencies {
       def nav_version = "2.0.1"
       classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
   }
}
    //add your pulgins after this like below:
 plugins {
  id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
  id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> Another way of adding your maps api can be done in following way where you don't need to add class path.

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
   id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
   id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
     //this is your maps class path.
   id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: If this helps you, accept this as an answer.